# Carrierwave, MiniMagick and resizing images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, image-uploading, minimagick

I am trying to make a simple rss/blog feed for a website. I want to have a simple uploader for the cover photo which will appear in the feed to the left of a caption with a read more link for blog posts. I thought in the image uploader file if you include mini_magick you have access to methods like version :medium do, etc. for different version of the image uploads. For whatever reason it just throws an error in the browser after I submit the form and it's not helpful at all. When I delete the version :medium do method in the uploader file the image uploads like normal but is small and I REALLY want to resize it.

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :fog

  version :medium do
      process resize_to_fit: [250, 250]
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end

class HomeBlog < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :upvotes
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end

<%= tinymce_assets %>
<%= simple_form_for(@admin_home_blog) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div>
    <h3>Upload a Cover Photo</h3>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <span class="form_labels"><%= f.input :name %></span>
    <%= f.text_area :entry, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 20, :cols => 120 %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Create Blog Post" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= tinymce %>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong? I also have the gem 'mini_magick' installed in the gemfile with carrierwave and fog.

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#adding-versions) part of CarrierWave's documentation. This is what I mean when I commented about calling the specific size! :)

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is not high enough to simply comment, but try this.

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :fog

  # move this line outside of your method
  process resize_to_fit: [512,512]         

  version :medium do

      # change the word 'fit' to 'fill'
      process resize_to_fill: [250,250]
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

From what I have seen all over and what I have had success with, is resizing to FIT just once (before each photo size method), and then resizing to FILL in all of the different photo sizes. Good luck!

Comment: Cool! I'll give that a try soon. I'll let you know what happens. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah it's still not resizing. At least it uploads the cover photo....Don't know why this is being so difficult. I'm beyond frustrated

Comment: There are methods to access the specific sizes. I believe it’s something like objectname.medium.url is how you call the photo (in an <%= image_tag %>) I’ll get back to you on this asap

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I call it like this: <%= image_tag p.image_url(:medium).to_s %>

Comment: The image is slightly bigger but it's definitely not resizing to the dimensions I'm setting in the medium version method in the uploader

Comment: Well, you do need to consider what potential styling options you have in your CSS that could be impacting that sizing as well. Carrierwave handles the metadata, whilst you still need to modify the sizing on the styling side (do a degree). If making sure your styling is right too, does not fix it, I'm out of answers at this point! Good luck, though.

Comment: I agree with you. I think it may be the css. I'm not exactly great at html or css so I'm hoping the answer lies in there otherwise I'm with ya, I don't know what the heck it could be lol. Thanks for you help though! Best of success to you as a developer

Comment: @dmberko11 absolutely and to you as well! If you do figure it out please share your findings! :)

Comment: I just said screw Mini_Magick and cheated with inline html styling haha. Was sick of wasting so much time on such a silly issue <%= image_tag p.image_url(:medium).to_s, style: 'height:400px;width:400px;' %>

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck and can't get Mini_Magick to work if you're using carrierwave or paperclip and just want to resize to a bigger image like I did? Simple in-line styling will suffice. Don't waste too much time with the version crap in the uploader file. Maybe some people don't have problems or they've cracked the code. Guess I'm special lol.

Comment: in-line styling is a bad solution because it is static.  When presented with something like dynamic uploads, any sound developer would want reusable uploaders.  Carrierwave is using libraries and there isn't good documentation on how to actually work with it, so I get your solution: but it's not the best way.